# Statistic on cancelled space projects

Tags: space-program, canceled-project

Do you know of any reliable statistics on the successrate of (aero)space project development?

How many projects suffer major delay and/or significant over budgets? How many projects get cancelled completly during development?

I'm mainly interested in official projects at the taxpayers expense, I'm not so much interested in private studies of companies or universities.

I guess that excludes also very early projects in Pre-Phase A (NASA)/ Phase 0 (ESA), since investments up to this point are quite small.

(For clarification: I'm working on a thesis about preliminary design methods and some numbers would come in handy to support my point that an approvement of conventional tools and methods would affect the successrate of big aerospace projects)

Comment: Please define **success**. There are lists of launchers at Wikipedia, and tons of unfinished designs are gathering dust in the archives.

Comment: Canceled at what stage? There's a huge difference if they cancel some train before I buy the ticket, or once I'm on it.

Comment: Regardless of definition, the statistics will not be pretty. Maybe for good reasons considering the easy ideas and the hard reality.

Comment: That is a very good question! I guess I would call it success if a project enters Operation (Life Cycle Phase E). But you could argue that a projects that leaves Development (Phase D) also counts as a succes.

I'm looking for projects that get cancelled due to major delays or significant over budgets during their development, that means somewhere inbetween Phases 0-D in their life cycles.

Comment: @LocalFluff I'm hoping for very ugly statistics to support my central argument that a change in preliminary design is desperately needed

Comment: "after a more or less significant amount " is not a very fine definition.  Would you say that Shuttle falls into your list? And it went on for 30 years.  In fact, I'd say that all US human spaceflight programs, by your definition, have been cancelled...except for ISS.

Comment: Yes you are right. I reworked the question. Feel free to comment on how to improve it :)

Comment: Can you link to a definition of the life cycle phases you're referring to?

Comment: @Hobbes  

ESA:  [ECSS-M-30A](http://www.lr.tudelft.nl/fileadmin/Faculteit/LR/Organisatie/Afdelingen_en_Leerstoelen/Afdeling_SpE/Space_Systems_Eng./Expertise_areas/Systems_engineering/References/doc/ecss-m-30a.pdf)  (Chapter 4) &

NASA: [SP-6105](https://foiaelibrary.gsfc.nasa.gov/_assets/doclibBidder/tech_docs/5.%20NASA%20SP-6105%20Rev%201%20%28Sys%20Eng%20Handbook%29.pdf) (Chapter 3)

Comment: You'd be well advised to couch the question in official terms from federal acquisition regulations, or any official guidance document.

Comment: What does "couch the question" mean? If you mean that I need a reliable source for my thesis, thats clear :) If not then please elaborate

Comment: I guess you'd want some decadal type [GAO](http://www.gao.gov/) reports?

Comment: @TildalWave:  The GAO reports seem to be an excellent source!!! How reliable is their information/point of view? As a non us-citizens I can't judge how neutral these reports are or if the GAO is doing some kind of lobby work!  

How can I mark your comment as an (possible) answer?